# my php isset is not working in POST method

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

This is my test.php code

```
<input type="button" value="click me" name="my_btn" onclick="mybtn();">

<?php
    echo("before is set");

    if(isset($_POST['hello'])=="dear"){
    echo("after is set true");
}
?>

<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
function mybtn(){

        $.ajax({
            url:"http://localhost/mysites/php_two/test.php",
            method:"post",
            data:{hello:"dear"},
        });

    }
</script>
```

when button is clicked,  page only shows
button icon + "before is set" text only.

But in Devtools network preview (in chrome browser), it shows
button icon +" before is setafter is set true"

please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: The network preview shows you what the response contains, that means `isset` is working. The example code lacks the `done` function, anything returned from an AJAX call must be handled in `done` function, that's the idea of AJAX, the request doesn't trigger page loading.

Comment: [isset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) will return a **bool**, you then compare it to a **string**, which will never be true. You want something like `if(isset($_POST['hello']) && $_POST['hello'] == "dear")`

Answer (score 1):

I think this want minimum 2 PHP pages 1st for show data and 2nd for creating data
 
**show.php**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="click me" name="my_btn" onclick="mybtn();">
<div id="dis">before is set</div>
<script>
   function mybtn(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "data.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:{hello:"dear"},
            success: function(result){
                $("#dis").html(result);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

**data.php**

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['hello']) && $_POST['hello']=="dear"){
        echo("after is set true");
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't mix `if(isset($_POST['hello'])=="dear")` because isset() takes a variable and check if it is set and not NULL which returns a boolean instead use it separate like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['hello']) && $_POST['hello']=="dear")
```